# Angular- Route Guard always redirects to home page before navigation

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-route-guards

I am trying to implement a route guard on my website. It checks for the token and then returns true or false. It is supposed to redirect if it returns false. However, when it is supposed to navigate it firstly  goes to "/" route before going to the desired route.

Eg.

**Current Behavior**

Check for token.

Token returns false.

Redirects to "/"

Then navigates to "/me/courses"

**Expected Behavior**

Check for token.

Token returns false

Navigates to "/me/courses"

This is my route guard

```
  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    var API_PATH = "auth/user/"
    var isAuthenticated = this.authService.isLoggedIn()

    if(!isAuthenticated) {
      return true
    }

    this.router.navigateByUrl("/me/courses")
    return false
  }
```

This is my code to check for the token

```
  loggedIn(autoFetchUserDetails = false) {
        if (autoFetchUserDetails) {
        this.fetchUserDetails();
    }
}

  isLoggedIn() {
      const token = this.globalService.getAuthToken();
      if (token) {
          if (!this.isAuth) {
            this.loggedIn(true);
          }
          return true;
      } else {
          if (this.isAuth) {
            this.logOut();
          }
          return false;
      }
    }

  fetchUserDetails() {
      const API_PATH = 'auth/user/';
      const SELF = this;
      this.api.getUrl(API_PATH).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.isAuth = true;
          this.user = data;
        },
        err => {
          this.globalService.deleteCookie(this.globalService.authStorageKey);
          this.logOut()
        }
      );
  }
```

Comment: @Farasi78 I am truly sorry, I copied and pasted that's why. Edited!!

Comment: That would be quite a task for me. Sorry @Farasi78

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are returning false. This tells the system to block the navigation completely.

If you want it to go to a different URL, such as "/me/courses", then you need to return a UrlTree object from the Route Guard, instead of false.

```
  canActivate(): boolean | UrlTree {
    var API_PATH = "auth/user/"
    var isAuthenticated = this.authService.isLoggedIn()

    if(!isAuthenticated) {
      return true
    }

    const tree: UrlTree = this.router.parseUrl("/me/courses");
    return tree;
  }
```